# Image asset widths in iOS need to be divisible by 8?

Tags: ios

All of a sudden, on an `iPad Air` we have here, all of the image assets in my app that have a width that is not divisible by 8 are corrupted.  It is pretty obvious visually that the problem is the wrong image pitch. Padding the images out to be divisible by 8 fixes the problem.

No big deal, but I can't find anything remotely like this by googling, which makes me worry that something else is wrong.  This just started happening with recent builds (so it may be an `XCode` version), and so far I've only seen it on one device (but I haven't yet tried other `iPad Air`s).  Edit: The affected device is running iOS 8, so that may be relevant.

Anybody else seen anything like this???

Edit #2: Confirmed that this is specific to iOS 8 (I've now reproduced it on a different device that had iOS 8.  Took me awhile to scrounge up another one, lol).  There are some unusual things about our build environment, so I'm trying to determine if that is relevant.  In any case, seems like I'm the only one with this problem, so that kinda answers my question...

Comment: What is 'corrupted', what image format, what's the size of the image, what's the size of the `UIImageView`?

Comment: No idea what is happening, but multiples of 8 is definitely not a requirement.

Comment: What is "corrupted" -- as I said, it's pretty obvious that it's the wrong image pitch (i.e. the image is skewed).  Format -- they are all PNG.  Size -- all sorts of sizes, but as I said, it's the ones with a width not divisible by 8 that are the problem.  Size of UIImageView -- same as the image, these are just UIImageViews that I've put in using the builder (many of which have been in our storyboard for literal years with no issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to confirm by making a test program that is literally nothing but a pair of UIImageViews with the Content Mode set to Center (one of them with dimensions 400x100 and another with dimensions 401x100) that if you build with XCode 9.2 and install on iOS 8, the images are corrupted for widths that are not divisible by 8.  I have no idea how I am the only one to stumble on this, but I did this with a clean project, clean workspace, and clean PNGs that I just created in GIMP expressly for this test.

So I guess... either end iOS 8 support (which we probably should have done a long time ago, amirite?) or pad your images?  Yuck.